# Get value from drop down and return to form field

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to get value from two form fields and then get their product and pass it to another form field .I am fetching data from database and then passing it dropdown.
But I am having trouble  .How can you get the selected value from drop down list using JavaScript? and then pass it to other field and some operation? I have tried the following but it does not work.My piece of work is down below.Anyone who can guide me?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">

  <div class="form-group">

      Months to rent 
     <div class="count-input space-bottom">
        <a class="incr-btn" data-action="decrease" href="#">+</a>
        <input onchange="calculate()" id="month" class="quantity " 
         type="text" name="quantity" value="1"/>
        <a class="incr-btn" data-action="increase" href="#"><i class="far 
         fa-plus-square"></i></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="s2id_autogen1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
    Select Room                        </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <select name="room_id" id="fee" class="form-control select2 select2- 
         offscreen" ">
            <?php
                include("connection.php");
                $id = $_GET['id'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM room  ";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                {
                 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                  {
             ?>
              <!--   Fee is an int value and description is room name -->

        <option id="fee" onchange="calculate()" value="<?php echo 
         $row['Fee']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Description']; ?></option>

             <?php  
                 } 
                }
              ?>

        </select >
     </div>
    <span class="col-sm-4 control-label"> </span>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
   Balance                
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" id="result" class="form-control" 
           name="checkin_date" >
    </div>
    <span class="col-sm-4 control-label">
    </span>
  </div>
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-8">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Add member">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript :

```
 <script>


    function calculate() {
        var myvar1 = document.getElementById('month').value; 
        var myvar2 = document.getElementById('fee').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result'); 
        var myResult = myvar1 * myvar2;
       document.getElementByid('result').value = myResult;

    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Tip: You shouldn't use ids with the same name more than once in a page. Ids are unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the value of the selected option like this. Run the snippet to see the result.

```js
function calculate() {
  var month_input = document.getElementById('month').value;
  var select_fee = document.getElementById('fee');
  var fee_input = select_fee.options[select_fee.selectedIndex].value
  var result = month_input * fee_input;
  document.getElementById('result').value = result;
}
```

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70px;
}

input {
  padding: 6px 14px;
}

.form-group {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Month:</label>
  <input onchange="calculate()" id="month" class="quantity " type="text" name="quantity" value="1" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Fees:</label>
  <select name="room_id" onchange="calculate()" id="fee" class="form-control select2 select2-offscreen">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <option value="100">Option 1</option>
    <option value="200">Option 2</option>
    <option value="300">Option 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label>Result:</label>
  <input type="text" id="result" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kumar.Can you also tell me how to calculate result of default drop down selected ?

Comment: You can simply call `calculate()` after the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

Your Javascript variables are all wrong...

You're setting myvar twice and then setting it to myBox1 * myBox2 which are never set.

I think what you're looking for is:

```
<script>
  function calculate() {
    var month_input = document.getElementById('month').value; 
    var fee_input = document.getElementById('fee').value;
    var result = month_input * fee_input;
    document.getElementById('result').value = myResult;
  }
</script>
```

You will also want to remove id="fee" from all of your <option> tags. By default, the value of a select is the value of its option that is selected.